# git reset HEAD file is not stopping the targeted file

Tags: git, github

As part of learning git, I'm trying to do like below.

1. Created two brand new `.txt` files with the names: `CommitThisFileButDontPush.txt`, and `SomeFile.txt` with some dummy content in it.
2. Used `git commit -m "Doing analysis"` message to stage these two files. After these two commands executed successfully, files are in staging phase.
3. Now, I 'DON'T' want to push `CommitThisFileButDontPush.txt` file to repository server, but just `SomeFile.txt`

I have executed the below command:

```
git reset HEAD -- Web2FA\Utils\CommitThisFileButDontPush.txt
```

Once after the above command is executed successfully, I have executed the below command to push changes to server.

```
git push -u origin master
```

When verified in the github.com website, found that both the files have been pushed to server. But, what I wanted is that:
**I DON'T want `CommitThisFileButDontPush.txt` to be pushed to repository server,** ***but I want this file locally***.

Can anyone please suggest me where I'm doing wrong, and what is the right approach!

Comment: If you commit something it becomes part of the history and will be pushed. You cannot exclude files from your history; that would make having a persistent and verifiable history quite useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a file to a commit and then push that commit, the file will be pushed as well.  When you push a commit, it pushes all the tree objects (directories) and blobs (files) that are in that commit.  This is just how Git works and it isn't avoidable.

`git reset HEAD` will unstage a change that you have staged with `git add` so that it is not committed when you run `git commit` (without the `-a` and `-A` flags).  However, once the file is committed, `git reset HEAD` won't affect whether already-committed data is pushed.

If you want a file to be present in your working tree, but not committed (and therefore not pushed), run `git rm --cached` on the file and commit and it will be left in your working tree but removed from future commits.  You can then ignore it in your `.gitignore` file.  If your goal is to avoid changing a tracked file, [that isn't possible](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_notes).

If you want to keep the changes locally but not push them, you could create a new branch and commit your changes there and then not push that branch.  You can then rebase your changes on the main development branch as necessary to keep your changes without affecting other branches.

Comment: Note that `git rm --cached` will only remove the file from the latest HEAD commit, but _not_ from the history. It still exists in all previous commits and other branches.